# If I do encryption/decryption in MySQL (as opposed to in the application), will the cleartext really be logged?

Tags: mysql, encryption, innodb

I am using the InnoDB MySQL engine.

I am doing the encryption in a stored procedure and then writing to the tables.

It seems like it would be logging the low-level changes to the DB.  That data is already encrypted (if it needed to be).

As I understand it, there are two different types of logs that can record changes to the DB:

1. The redo log (ib_logfile group), which fixes half-done transaction in the event of a crash.
2. The binary log, which is used for replication and restoring from backup.

   (source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_ib_logfile)

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Found a good link regarding the binary log:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html

But I would still like to know about the redo log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be. If your MySQL server is set to log all statements to the general query log, or if you have binary logging enabled and not set to use the row-based format, the clear text and key will be logged there.

Additionally, doing encryption/decryption in the database may expose your data to an attacker who can modify stored procedures. It's generally not a good idea; I'd avoid it.

Comment: I'm using the built-in AES functions.  The key is never written to a DB table.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you're logging statements, either intentionally or accidentally, the `AES_ENCRYPT()` (or DECRYPT) call, and its arguments, will be saved on the database server.

Comment: If you would have looked at my source link, you would have read that those two types of log files only record statements that "attempt to change table data."  And my reasoning is, the logging engine doesn't know my SP will change some tables, so it must operate at something lower than the SP level -- perhaps the insert/update level, at which point the data is already encrypted.  And the key is not included in the insert/update data.

Comment: SQL statements can also be recorded in the general query log (`general_log`). As far as the binary log goes, that depends on the binary logging format, which can be set to statement-based, row-based, or "mixed". Calls to stored procedures are always stored in the binary log (whether they alter data or not) unless it's set to row-based.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the general log. I'm happy to disable that.  Thank you for the info on the binary log.  I would still like to know about item #1 -- the "redo log".

Comment: The redo log is row-based, so it won't contain the source statement.

Comment: Excellent.  That was my hunch, but I couldn't find a source.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: The redo log is part of the InnoDB storage engine, and MySQL storage engines don't operate on a statement level. :)

Answer (score 0):

On what knowledge do you base the idea that cleartext will be logged? What does the stored procedure exactly do?

Comment: I have seen warnings from end users (not anything more authoritative) about doing encryption in the DB because of incoming cleartext being logged.

Comment: My SP takes some clear text (and a key), encrypts it, inserts it in a table, and returns the row ID.

Answer (score 0):

Cleartext is logged, that is the what the OP is asking about I think.

```
    mysql> insert into new_table (col2, col3) values(des_encrypt('asdf1234'),des_encrypt('thisissecret'));
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

    [root@test mysql]# mysqlbinlog -s test-bin.000001 | grep secret
    insert into new_table (col2, col3) values(des_encrypt('asdf1234'),des_encrypt('thisissecret'))
```

Comment: The binary log can be set to do row-based logging instead of statement-based logging.  Row-based logging will not log the cleartext.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to encrypt the data in the application. Any logging from there on will have the data encrypted. We use `PHP` to encrypt using `mcrypt`.

```
$key = mhash(MHASH_MD5, $key);
$cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$vector = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher_alg, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$CC_number = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, "4111111111111111", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $vector);
$CC_name = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, "Prion Interactive", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $vector);
```

For PCI Compliance, you really need to have a `separate key server` that stores the encryption keys separately. PCI auditors are very hesitant to pass `CC data` in MySQL binlogs, even if you are using row-based replication. It's too easy for someone to change that.

Comment: But one could always write a daily-run test that fails when the mode is not correct.